# Is it possible to store elements of a matrix raw as a string array in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab

Is there any smart way to store elements of a matrix raw as a string array?

For example:

If `A=[1 2 3; 4 5 6]` a 2x3 matrix, `str(1)='1 2 3'` and `str(2)='4 5 6'`; a 1x2 array

Answer (score 4):

There is a way (whether it is smart or not) to convert the matrix to a cell array of strings:

```
>> str = cellstr(num2str(A));

str = 

'1  2  3'
'4  5  6'
```

Input matrix `A` is converted to an 2x7 array of characters (two spaces between each number) via `num2str`, and then we convert it to a cell array of strings via `cellstr`.  The first string is accessed by `str{1}` and the second by `str{2}`.

Comment: was just about to add that option too... +1

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to make it workout syntactically exactly like you requested.  I see two options:

1. As Geoff mentioned `str = cellstr(num2str(A))` will get the job done and you'll have to index it as `str{1}` (note that `str(1)` returns a cell array and not a string).
2. If you want an array, you can just use `str = num2str(A)`

eg

```
>> num2str(A)
ans =
1  2  3
4  5  6
>> str(1,:)
ans =
1  2  3
>> str(2,:)
ans =
4  5  6
```

Kept as a vector, you'll have to access your string with `str(1,:)`.